# Can i have shorten this program

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap

I do not prefer giving arraylist values dynamically when running. But I need loops for ArrayList and hashTable, to shorten program.

```
public class HashTable2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<String>> hasTable1 = new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
        
        ArrayList<String> arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrList4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrList5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrList6 = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrList1.add("MasoodAzar, 10000, Finance");
        arrList2.add("Abu Bakr, 20000, Logistics");
        arrList3.add("MuhammedRasul, 5000, Sales");
        arrList4.add("SubhanQuershi, 2500, Sales");
        arrList5.add("Hafiz Saeed, 25000, Purchase");
        arrList6.add("Shekau, 14500, Purchase");

        hasTable1.put(251, arrList1);
        hasTable1.put(355, arrList2);
        hasTable1.put(754, arrList3);
        hasTable1.put(384, arrList4);
        hasTable1.put(463, arrList5);
        hasTable1.put(835, arrList6);

        System.out.println(hasTable1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... why are you using ArrayLists?

Comment: Why are you using `Hashtable` rather than `HashMap`?

Comment: ArrayList used to store employee details to the particular key and i need to fetch values based on some condition. For example i need to Find the employees whosesalary is above 7500

Comment: The task is for me to create HashTable with the above data. (Key: Integer, Values: Arraylist)

Comment: So you want a loop to initialize ArrayList objects, and a loop to put objects in hashMap?

Comment: Yes exactly L.Papadopoulos. Sorry not hashMap, it is Hashtable

Comment: @SelvaSPM each arraylist contains exactly one String, that is pointless

Comment: Why do you have 6 ArrayList's with one element each? You could use a HashMap<Integer, String>.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to abstract away the repetitive code:

```
void addEmployee(Hashtable hashTable, int id, String employeeDetails) {
  ArrayList<String> employees = new ArrayList<>();
  employees.add(employeeDetails);
  hashTable.put(id, employees);
}
```

You should use HashMap rather than Hashtable -- Hashtable is synchronised, which isn't necessary here.

You should probably also represent the employees with a class, with fields fo reach of their attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much tgdavies for your help!